# Is there a name for the midpoint along the radius of an arc?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there a name for the point **on the radius** of an arc that is equidistant on both ends of the arc?  Is it midpoint? Apex?

Comment: The question is unclear. Whatever you are trying to describe when you write "radius," it seems it cannot be what everyone else would call a radius. In [the picture linked here](https://cdn.inchcalculator.com/a/img/shapes/sector-2.png) the dashed line segment labeled $a$ is a *chord* of the arc labeled $s.$ The line segment labeled $r$ is *a radius* of the arc, but it is not "the radius": the unlabeled line segment also is a radius, and likewise any segment connecting the intersection of those segments to any point on the arc is a radius. *The radius* is simply the length of a radius.

Comment: Since *the radius* of an arc is just a length, not a line segment, there are no points on it. But the "other" endpoint of *a radius* of a circular arc is the *center* of the arc (that is, each radius has one endpoint on the arc; the other endpoint is the center of the arc). And the center of an arc is at the same distance from both endpoints of the arc. In fact it is the same distance from all points on the arc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the [chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)) as *radius of an arc*, as far as I know, there is no specific terminology for that. You can maybe just call it the *midpoint of a chord*.

Answer (score 2):

I would just call it the **midpoint of a chord** or **chord bisector** (because it bisects the chord).